# JSF EL: how to pass parameters to value expression?

Tags: parameters, el, jsf-2.2

```
@ManagedBean("myBean")
public class MyBean {

    public String getId(String name) {...}
}


#{myBean.id('foo')}
```

JSF trying to resolve `MyBean.getId('foo')()`. How to pass parameter to value expression?

JSF 2.2.

Tried: #{myBean.getId('foo')}, not working. JSF tried to resolve `MyBean.getGetId('foo')()`.

Comment: can't you rename bean method to id(String name) instead of getId(String name) ? It is not getter because there is method parameter.

Comment: Tried id(String name). JSF still looks for getId('foo')().

Answer (score 0):

The first issues is the `@ManagedBean` annotation. If you're on JSF 2.2, you should not be using `@ManagedBean` as those have been sunset for a few years. Instead, use the modern CDI annotations that have a well-defined scope.

Try the following instead:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {

    public String getId(String name) {...}
}
```

Next with the EL expression, invoke the `getId()` function like this:

```
#{myBean.getId('foo')}
```

You cannot use property-like expressions because the `getId(...)` method takes an argument and does not follow the JavaBean standard (see here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/Introspector.html)

You could theoretically create your own `ELResolver` that supported this if you wished. (https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/business-&-other/9781782176466/1/ch01lvl1sec13/writing-a-custom-el-resolver)